# creating two byte, two-dimensional array in Python

Tags: python

I am new to python programming and I have c and c++ background. I need to create two-dimensional array (Not a list) which each element is two bytes and save it to a file (as a binary file). I learned that if I create a two-dimensional list and use the bytearray function I can save the list to a binary file, but unfortunately the bytearray cannot have more than one byte value. Any hints and guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish.  For instance, why do you want to create a 2d array of 2B?  There may be better techniques to your end goal with python, even.  Also, including code in a language you're familiar with as an example may also help get your question answered.

Comment: Does the array need to be saved in a specific format? I know you can use the pickle module to save objects (such as a list) to a file as a byte stream. Is there a reason you don't want to use a list? You can save bytes to a list (and even two at a time!). `L = [b'\xaa\xbb', b'\xcc\xdd']`

Comment: the binary file will be read by firmware (c language)  uploading through serial port. I have a two-dimensional array in c code "unsigned short array[x][y]" which I need to copy the file to this array. I don't mind to use list but I don't know how I can convert the list to binary. I tried bytearray function but this function cannot handle over one byte (0~255)